# Random division of list to two complementary sublists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, random

I have a list which I want to randomly divide into two sublists of known size, which are complements of one another. e.g., I have `[1,5,6,8,9]` and I want to divide it to `[1,5,9]` and `[6,8]`. I care less about efficiency and just want it to work. Order does not matter.

I started with:

```
pop = [...] #some input
samp1 = random.sample(pop, samp1len)
samp2 = [x for x in pop if x not in samp1]
```

However, this solution fails with repetitive items. If `pop = [0,0,0,3,5]`, and the first selection of length 3 was `[0,3,5]`, I would still like samp2 to be `[0,0]`, which my code currently fails to provide.

Is there some built in option in random that I missed? Can anyone offer a simple solution?

Comment: So order of items also matters?

Comment: I wrote in the question - it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this?

Generate a list of indices and shuffle them:

```
>>> indices = range(len(pop))
>>> random.shuffle(indices)
```

Then slice the indices list and use `operator.itemegetter` to get the items:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> itemgetter(*indices[:3])(pop)
(0, 0, 3)
>>> itemgetter(*indices[3:])(pop)
(5, 0)
```

Comment: In Python 3, range returns a lazy sequence object. You have to convert the object to a list before getting the items: indices = list(range(len(pop)))